# Hide field label with hook_form_alter()

Tags: forms

In `hook_form_alter()`, I am trying to disable/hide a field label in a custom form. I know I could use `$form['my_field']['#enableLabel'] = FALSE;`.

Is there a way without unsetting the title?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unsetting not really, hide yes : use [#title_display](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!form.inc/function/template_preprocess_form_element/8.4.x) and its get accessible to screenreader :

```
$form['my_field']['#title_display'] = 'invisible';
```

Comment: Just to mention that if you're using, say a *List (text)* field, you need to refer to the widget to hide the title: `$form['my_field']['widget']['#title_display'] = 'invisible';`

Comment: Every field has a different array structure to set invisible values. I didn't find #title_display with dropdown widget,

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was trying to hide the label on quantity field provided by Drupal Commerce cart module and the following wasn't working:

```
$form['my_field']['#title_display'] = 'invisible';
```

I had to do this inside my hook_form_alter

```
$form['quantity']['widget'][0]['value']['#title_display'] = 'invisible';
```

Comment: Thank u. That's also works for me.

Answer (score -1):

you can try:

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

    $form['title']['widget']['0']['value']['#title_display']=none;

 }
```

**Note:** change "title" by your machine name field.

Comment: I do not understand how they put votes down if the code works well for me. Could you explain this to me? They should prohibit putting votes down if an explanation is not given.

Comment: Downvotes are anonymous by design, that's not going to change. You can avoid them quite easily, though. For example, you said _the code works well for me_, when any PHP developer will be able to tell you that's simply not true, just by glancing at your answer. First of all, it's invalid PHP. You haven't quoted a string. Second of all, it's invalid in the context of hiding a title in Drupal. The correct string to hide a title is "invisible", as you can see in the accepted answer above. It's always a good idea to check your work before trying to lay blame at the feet of others